# Can I use an if, then to reference a particular Google Doc based on Google Sheet info

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-docs

I have a Script that reliably replaces certain values within double curly brackets in my Google Doc. The values are taken from a Google Sheet that is populated using Google Form answers. I want one of the questions to be "plural or singular", and for the answer to determine whether the Google Doc with singular tenses or plural tenses is used. Is there a way to use an "if, then" so that if my Google Sheet says "singular", the appropriate Google Doc is filled, and if the Google Sheet says "plural", the other Google Doc is filled?

I tried replacing the portion of code that references the Google Doc with an if then where:

if (that e.value) is 'singular', then the FileID is (the Google Doc ID), and if else, the FileID is (the other Google Doc ID)

But no dice. There's no error message. Just doesn't work. Any ideas?

TLDR: I have two Google Sheets, and I want to be able to answer a question on Google Forms that picks which sheet gets filled with the rest of the information from the Form/Sheet

Comment: Please provide [mcve]

Comment: `But no dice` Don't know why that should be. There's nothing "special" about aligning Google Sheets values with Google Docs merge codes. No reason why an `if then` shouldn't work. Please supply the code.

Answer (score 0):

```
function onFormSubmit(e) {
  let obj = { "Singular": "Sheet1", "plural": "Sheet2" }
  let sheet = obj[e.value[x]];
  if (sheet) {

  } else {
    return
  }
}
```

[For additional explanation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript)

Comment: Your answer contains code without explanation. It's better to include details about *how* your answer answers the question.